# how to split "1$$$$" use awk

Tags: linux, shell

if I have a string like "sn":"1$$$$12056597.3,2595585.69$$", how can I use awk to split "1$$$$"

I tried

```
**cat $filename | awk -F "\"1\$\$\$\$" '{ print $2 }'**
**cat $filename | awk -F "\"1$$$$" '{ print $2 }'**
```

but all failed

Comment: What do you mean 'split "1$$$$"'?  Split what on what?   What should `awk` print out when given your example string?

Comment: maybe you can get that to work, but why build a solution that you won't be able to remember how it works, much less someone else having to maintain such a problem. If your source data provider can't provide  you with a usable file, then preprocess the file to change '$' to <tab> chars, or something else and then use awk without the tears ;-) ... Good luck.

Comment: put content of your filename

Comment: because your awk make all of data in $1 , So print $2 is NULL.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh the content is like this:"sn":"1$$$$12056597.3,2595585.69$$"

Answer (score 2):

any number of $ use

```
echo '"1$$$$12056597.3,2595585.69$$"' | awk -F '"1[$]+' '{ print $2 }'
```

exactly 4 use

```
echo '"1$$$$12056597.3,2595585.69$$"' | awk -F '"1[$]{4}' '{ print $2 }'
```

to help debug problems with escape characters in the shell you can use the built-in shell command *set* which will print the arguments that are being passed to awk after the shell has interpreted any escape characters and replaced shell variables

In this case the shell first interprets \$ as an escape for a plain $

```
set -x
echo '"1$$$$12056597.3,2595585.69$$"'|awk -F "\"1\$\$\$\$" '{ print $2 }'
+ echo '"1$$$$12056597.3,2595585.69$$"'
+ awk -F '"1$$$$' '{ print $2 }'
```

You can use \$ so the \$ get to awk, but \$ is interpreted in awk regular expressions as a $ anyway. At least awk is nice enough to warn you...

```
echo '"1$$$$12056597.3,2595585.69$$"'|awk -F "\"1\\$\\$\\$\\$" '{ print $2 }'
+ echo '"1$$$$12056597.3,2595585.69$$"'
+ awk -F '"1\$\$\$\$' '{ print $2 }'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\$' treated as plain `$'
```

Turn off debugging with

```
set +x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '"1$$$$12056597.3,2595585.69$$"' | awk -F '"1[$]+' '{ print $2 }' |sed 's/.\{3\}$//'
```

Or if you want to split both float digit:

```
echo '"1$$$$12056597.3,2595585.69$$"' | awk -F '"1[$]+' '{ print $2 }' |sed 's/.\{3\}$//' |awk 'BEGIN {FS=","};{print $1}'
```

And

```
echo '"1$$$$12056597.3,2595585.69$$"' | awk -F '"1[$]+' '{ print $2 }' |sed 's/.\{3\}$//' |awk 'BEGIN {FS=","};{print $2}'
```